# How does diffraction apply to the human eye?

Tags: optics

What aperture in the human eye would be involved with diffraction   & what diffraction occurs in the eye, location wise

Answer (score 2):

The angular resolution of the human eye is diffraction-limited and arises from the finite pupil diameter. We can only differentiate points which are separated at least by an angular distance of [about 1 arcminute](http://www.wikilectures.eu/index.php/Resolution_of_human_eye). This matters a lot for amateur astronomers: Double stars can only be resolved with the naked eye if they are further apart than the angular resolution.